# Subqueries problem (look for the highest date before X date)

Tags: sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'd like to calculate the stock the company had in some given dates. Since we don't have a table of stocks, I need to calculate it based on stock movements. `ENTRAN` = add and `SALEN` = substract, starting from last inventory before that date.

The dates I have to check are the last days with stock movement before a sale.

I'd like to work with my sales table connected to the movement stock table.

The stock movements table (`MOVSTOCKS`) look like this:

```
SKU     entran     salen     codalm     fecdoc         tipdoc    
ART1      50        10          2       01-03-2021      IN
ART1      100                   2       03-03-2021      AC
ART1                30          2       05-03-2021      AV
ART2      100       50          2       01-03-2021      IN
ART2                50          2       02-03-2021      AV
ART2      30        50          2       03-03-2021      IN 
ART2                20          2       03-03-2021      AV
ART2      50                    2       04-03-2021      AC
ART2                30          2       05-03-2021      AV
```

Each `IN` is an inventory. I have to take the `ENTRAN` value when there's an inventory, and keep calculating from there, adding or substracting units.

`AC` are purchases and `AV` are sales.

So, the sales table (`LINEALBA`) should show this data, among other columns:

```
Date          SKU      QTY      Cumulative
05-03-2021    ART1     30          150
02-03-2021    ART2     50          100
03-03-2021    ART2     20          30
05-03-2021    ART2     30          60
```

Each row is a sale (`AV`), and the `cumulative` column is looking at the last inventory before that sale `01-03-2021` or `03-03-2021`, it adds and substracts quantities, and shows the calculated stock for the day before the sale.

This is my query (not working):

```
select  *
from    (select     m*,
                    LastInventory + sum(m.entran - m.salen) 
                       over (partition by m.codart order by m.fecdoc) as cumulative,
                    max(m.fecdoc) over (partition by m.codart) as max_fecdoc,
                    m.fecdoc
        from        MovStocks m
        left join   LINEALBA l on l.codart = m.codart
        left join   (select     m2.codart as SKU,
                                m2.entran as LastInventory,
                                max(m2.fecdoc) over (partition by m2.codart, m2.tipdoc) as LastDateinventory,
                                m2.fecdoc
                    from        MovStocks m2
                    where       m2.codalm in (2)
                    and         m2.tipdoc = 'IN') m2
            on      m2.CODART = m.codart
        where       m.codalm in (2)
        and         m2.fecdoc = LastDateinventory
        and         m.fecdoc < v.fecha
        and         m.fecdoc > LastDateinventory
        and         LastDateinventory < v.fecha
        and         m.tipdoc <> 'IN') m
        where       max_fecdoc = m.fecdoc
```

My idea is to create one subquery, or a CTE, Idk, that sees when was the last inventory before the sale, and sees when was the last movement before the sale, and then calculates the stock taking the inventory as a base (like if it was a 0).

For some reason, my query is not calculating this cumulative correctly. I don't know if it's a problem on the filter or if my subquery is not correct...

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` here? You have no related aggregation in your inner or outer queries.

Comment: @Larnu I had some duplicated rows because of the `entran` and `salen`, but I couldn't show data without grouping the inner query by these two columns. So I grouped the inner query with entran and salen, and the outer query without them.

Comment: This normally means your `JOIN` (well more specifically your `ON`) clauses are wrong. doing a `GROUP BY` on every column with no aggregation is pointless and confusing; you'd be better off (if you must) using `DISTINCT`, however, I am more certain the problem is your `JOIN`s with some kind of many to one/many relationship causing "duplicate" (they won't true identical, so aren't true duplicate) rows. That, or you shouldn't be using windowed aggregation in the inner query and the outer `GROUP BY` should be completely removed.

Comment: Okay, I deleted both inner and outer grouping. With `DISTINCT` I get the same ammount of rows. That's good. Now the problem is the cumulative. I don't know how can I manage to calculate it properly, and I have no idea if my subquery is correct or if there's a problem with the filters: 
       `and m2.fecdoc = LastDateinventory`,
        `and m.fecdoc < v.fecha`,
        `and m.fecdoc > LastDateinventory`,
       `and LastDateinventory < v.fecha`,
        `and m.tipdoc <> 'IN'`

Comment: Edit your question to be a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), make your query compact and concise to just illustrate the problem you are trying to solve, along with sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Stu Okay. I edited the question and the query (now it is showing only the subqueries and the filters giving me problems. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conqueror!

```
-- Add sequence number with SKU.
-- Rows may be uniquely identify by SKU & seq number.
With Qry1 As (
    SELECT      SKU,
                entran,
                salen,
                codalm,
                fecdoc,
                tipdoc,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By SKU Order By fecdoc) As Seq
    FROM        MOVSTOCKS
),

-- Get seq # of most recent inventory for each SKU.
Qry2 As (
    SELECT      qry11.sku,
                qry11.seq,
                max(qry12.seq) as prev_inv_seq
    FROM        Qry1 qry11
    inner join  Qry1 qry12
    on          qry11.sku = qry12.sku
    and         qry11.fecdoc >= qry12.fecdoc
    where       qry12.tipdoc = 'IN'
    group by    qry11.sku,
                qry11.seq
), 

-- Get quantity of most recent inventory for each SKU.
Qry3 As (
    SELECT      qry2.sku,
                qry2.seq,
                qry1.entran as prev_inv_entran
    FROM        Qry2 
    inner join  Qry1
    on          qry2.sku = qry1.sku
    and         qry2.prev_inv_seq = qry1.seq
), 

-- Get sum of purchase quantities since most recent inventory for each SKU.
Qry4 As (
    SELECT      qry2.sku,
                qry2.seq,
                sum(qry1.entran) as sum_entran
    FROM        Qry2 
    inner join  Qry1 qry1
    on          qry2.sku = qry1.sku
    where       qry1.seq > qry2.prev_inv_seq
    and         qry1.seq < qry2.seq
    AND         qry1.tipdoc = 'AC'
    group by    qry2.sku,
                qry2.seq
), 

-- Get sum of sales quantities since most recent inventory for each SKU.
Qry5 As (
    SELECT      qry2.sku,
                qry2.seq,
                sum(qry1.salen) as sum_salen
    FROM        Qry2 
    inner join  Qry1 qry1
    on          qry2.sku = qry1.sku
    where       qry1.seq > qry2.prev_inv_seq
    and         qry1.seq < qry2.seq
    AND         qry1.tipdoc = 'AV'
    group by    qry2.sku,
                qry2.seq
)

-- Pull it all together...
SELECT      qry1.fecdoc As Date,
            qry1.SKU,
            qry1.salen As Quantity,
            qry3.prev_inv_entran + IsNull(qry4.sum_entran, 0) - IsNull(qry5.sum_salen, 0) as Cumulative
FROM        qry1
left JOIN   Qry3
on          qry3.sku = qry1.sku
and         qry3.seq = qry1.seq
left JOIN   Qry4
on          qry4.sku = qry1.sku
and         qry4.seq = qry1.seq
left JOIN   Qry5
on          qry5.sku = qry1.sku
and         qry5.seq = qry1.seq
WHERE       qry1.tipdoc = 'AV'
```